# Extensions disappear when I close and open Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am running the latest version of Google Chrome `23.0.1271.97 (Official Build 171054) m` on Windows 7. Any new extension I install simply disappears (not disabled, total disappearance) once I close and re-start Google Chrome. This is not happening to any of my old extensions; they stay there across Chrome re-starts.

I tried everything Google Help suggested:

1. I created new user profile by renaming the `Defaults` folder
2. I checked for any permission change that the extensions might have undergone. This is not the case.
3. I am not running in developer mode.

This happens when I close **all** instances of Google Chrome. Even if one instance of Chrome is running, this doesn't happen. But I can't have an instance of Google Chrome always running.

I even reported the issue to Google Chrome team to no avail and [new.crbug.com](http://new.crbug.com) is offline. And I skimmed through many threads opened for the same issue only to find souls like me. Stack Exchange is my last resort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, with hints from [Andy Lech's Answer](https://superuser.com/a/519912/83812), I was able to solve this problem (atleast a temporary fix). Here are the quick steps-

- Go to **Settings** by typing **chrome://settings** in your URL bar
- Under **Sign In**, select **Sign in to Chrome**.
- Sign in with your Google Account Username and password.
- A pop asking you to **Confirm Sync Settings** appears. Press **OK, Sync
  Everything**. Dont worry you can customize the items you want to sync
  to your Google account later. But make sure Extensions are checked
  and synced
- Now, go ahead and install new extensions from Chrome Webstore
- Re-start Google Chrome. Close all instances of Chrome.
- Wait for some time. As you can see, all your extensions get loaded
  over a short time period I've written a detailed blog about this
  which can be found here

You can read more below-

[Are your Google Chrome Extensions disappearing out of nowhere?](http://rendezvouswithpavan.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/are-your-google-chrome-extensions-disappearing-out-of-nowhere-heres-a-temporary-fix/)

Comment: @slhck Thanks for the tip. I added the quick steps into the body of the answer itself!

Answer (score 8):

Do you have your extensions set to sync to a Google account?

I have the same version and I have been having a similar problem with all my extension settings being reset every time I do a clean launch of Chrome.  Here is a temporary fix that worked for me:

1. Open your Settings by using the menu item Tools => Setting or browsing to chrome://settings/
2. Click the "Advanced sync settings..." button under "Sign in"
3. Change "Sync everything" to "Choose what to sync"
4. Uncheck Extensions
5. Click Ok
6. Close every instance of Chrome and do a clean launch (or just reboot your computer to be safe)

Of course, this is only a temporary fix because it makes all your extension settings local to that computer, but for me that is better that reapplying all my extension settings every time I launch Chrome.

Comment: Boy oh boy! The reverse of what you suggest seems to be working for me. I'd never signed in to Google Chrome with my Google account. In order to see if your solution works, I did for the first time with the option "Sync All" selected! I installed a few new extensions and  restarted Chrome. Voila, all my extensions gradually popped up!!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem in a simpler way. First, click the Wrench, then Settings, then Extensions. Check the box to enable developer mode.

You will now see the file's location and name highlighted blue. Copy the path and use either Run or the Start menu search bar to reach that path. Delete that file and afterwards you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way of fixing this issue. Go to the "more tools" menu and select Task Manager. This is for only Google Task Manager and kill process for all extensions. Go back Tools\setting\extensions. You may remove delete any extension now.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Wrench Menu In **Chrome -> Tools -> Extensions** this will give you extensions list.. 
now take your **.crx** file and drag on this page .. this will permanently installed extensions..