# All chrome extensions disabled on startup

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I restart chrome it opens with all extensions disabled. I uninstalled/reinstalled chrome and this did not fix the problem, and I still have to manually enable every extension each time I start Chrome.

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question here: https://superuser.com/q/519300/180580 The temporary fix I describe there may work for you also: https://superuser.com/a/519912/180580